# git branching information

Tags: git

I have a git repository named main_repo where the contents are

```
      HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

i clone the git directory with `git clone main_repo test_branch`

then

```
      cd test_branch
      git branch new_branch
      git branch gives me 
         * master
         new_branch
```

My question is how to check this branch into the main_repo
and also can i see the new_branch in main_repo branch directory .

Comment: 1. git checkout new_branch. 2. push the branch back to main_repo (named origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main_repo` is a "naked" git repository. You're not supposed to us it directly.

Please see this article on how to [push a new local branch to a remote git repository](http://www.mariopareja.com/blog/archive/2010/01/11/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

to change local branch:

git checkout new_branch

To push to remote repo:

git push origin new_branch.